# How do I create a vector of cv::matrix in opencv and assign submatrix of image data to matrices on all index of vector

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to create a vector of cv::Matrix in a c++ program and on each index i want to copy the submatrix of an image, for example;
`vector<Mat> VectorMat;

VectorMat[i]=threshImage(cv::Rect(x,y,max.x-min.x,max.y-min.y));`
But this is not working, I also tried to use loop method in which I am using `mat.at<uchar>(row,col`) to copy the matrix data in sub matrix, but program hangs.
What is the best way to get the submatrix in opencv and copy it in a vector of cv::Mat

Thank You

Comment: can you explain more what's 'not working'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a real copy you can do

```
VectorMat[i]=threshImage(cv::Rect(x,y,max.x-min.x,max.y-min.y)).clone();
```

or

```
threshImage(cv::Rect(x,y,max.x-min.x,max.y-min.y)).copyTo(VectorMat[i]);
```

Comment: Thanks second call worked, only change was it should copyto a cv::Mat and then pushback to the vector of cv::Mat

Comment: push_back is needed only if you have not resized your vector to the required size before the loop. If you know final number of matrices then resize + one of my suggestions will be a bit more performant than push_bask inside the cycle.